# unable to print correctly QGIS maps

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I already ask how to print a map without screwing the "sync" between my map and the Openlayers background. I have tried 2.6.0 and 2.8.1 versions getting only deep frustration.
I have used the scale suggested to have optimal results, getting a wonderful series of failures.
On the screen the map looks perfect, once printed on PDF it slides out of sync.
I want to think I am doing something wrong because is hard to believe after so many years we have still to deal with this bug.
I love QGIS and what it allows me to do, but not been able to print my maps really make me @#$%$#@@#$##$@#@@#$&*%^%.
Help please.

Comment: also worth noting that you're experiencing a bug in a 3rd party QGIS plugin, not in QGIS itself. You need to contact the plugin maintainer for support - this is nothing that the QGIS team can fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [Bug report #5827 Printing issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827)